# How I add a co-author to my Google Scholar profile?

Tags: google-scholar

I have co-authored some publications with an author who has a Google Scholar profile, but I see no way of adding him to my profile as a co-author.

How I add a co-author to my Google Scholar profile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The recipe is this:

1. `Sign In` to [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/).
2. Click on `My Citations`.
3. Type your co-author name in the search box provided (top right).
4. You will get a list of authors that match the search. Click on the "Add co-author" button on the right of the correct person.

   - If your author is not found, you will get a failed search.

If you click on the wrong person, you can remove them with the edit button at the top of your co-authors list.